# What is a current, functional replacement for md5 cryptography in PHP?

Tags: php, cryptography, md5

I hear md5 is long dated and obselete. What are my alternative options?

Many thanks.

Comment: @Marc a system of mine was analysed by some ethical hackers and they claimed md5 was flawed

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is currently the most secure one-way encryption algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329582/what-is-currently-the-most-secure-one-way-encryption-algorithm)

Comment: What is your use case? Any answer here is wrong before they know what you want to use it for.

Comment: Just to complement the answers, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Answer (score 2):

I recommened you to use SHA-2 family. The SHA-2 family of hash functions are the current replacement of SHA-1. The members of SHA-2 are individually referred to as SHA-224, SHA-256, SHA-384, and SHA-512.

For a hash, you basically just want to choose the largest block size possible, and use a salt value to avoid rainbow attacks.

if you need to replace MD5 in an application where using a hash was a bad design choice in the first place, which include many uses in conjunction with password (protection of login information, or generation of a key from a password), then you do not want just to replace MD5; you want to change the design.

Answer (score 1):

Google pbkdf2.  There are implementations in PHP out there, and it's a one-stop-shop for complete password protection.  If you're just hashing the password and then done with it, md5 is a little worse than sha1, which is a little worse than sha256, etc, but they're all vulnerable to rainbow tables.  Make sure you're using proper salting techniques at minimum, and to really do it right you should use an algorithm like pbkdf2, the object of which is to make it computationally intensive to brute force (with a dash of obscurity in there as well, since it requires the attacker to know the number of iterations you're using, not just the algorithm).

Comment: PBKDF2 is good for password protection, but I cannot see if the asker is actually aiming for that. Maybe he is, maybe not...